# Assign a group for user programmatically

Tags: odoo-8, assign

I have enabled sign up functionality in my odoo instance, after sign up i need to assign certain group to that user automatically.
I have inherited res.user model tried to extend -get_group function like below:

```
class res_users(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'res.users'
_description = 'Inherit res users model'
     def _get_group(self,cr, uid, context=None):
        dataobj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
        result = []
        print'inside _get_group'
        try:
            dummy,group_id = dataobj.get_object_reference(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, 'base', 'group_user')
            result.append(group_id)
            dummy,group_id = dataobj.get_object_reference(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, 'base', 'group_partner_manager')
            result.append(group_id)
          **dummy,group_id = dataobj.get_object_reference(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, 'ams', 'group_residents')
            result.append(group_id)**
        except ValueError:
           # If these groups does not exists anymore
           pass
        return result
```

But this function doesn't execute.. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to override base model methods, you should first call the parent function and then make changes to the result that is returned by the parent function. This will take care of the sequence in which the methods are called. Something like this should do it for you:

```
class res_users(models.Model)
_inherit = 'res.users'

def _get_group(self,cr, uid, context=None):
    dataobj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    # Calls the parent function
    result = super(res_users,self)._get_group(cr, uid, context=context)
    try:
        dummy,group_id = dataobj.get_object_reference(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, 'ams', 'group_residents')
    result.append(group_id)
    except ValueError:
        # If these groups does not exists anymore
        pass
    return result
```

Comment: Did you inherit 'res.users'? I don't think the model is called 'res.user'. And are you calling this method "result = super(res_users,self)._get_group(cr, uid, context=context)" in your _get_group()? Could you also update the question above with the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

When using the signup feature the new users inherit whatever access your template user has. Take a look at the portal template user in settings > users. Add the portal template user to the groups you wish new users to be a part of (or any other defaults).